# TypeScript doesn't always enforce function signatures

Tags: typescript

Let's say I create a typed object where the key is a string, and the value is a function that takes in a number and returns nothing:

```
let funcMap: { [id: string]: (num: number) => void };
```

When I assign functions to this object, the type checking doesn't seem to be enforced:

```
funcMap = {
  // This is OK, as expected

  'one': (num: number) => { },

  // I would expect this be an error because there is no string function parameter

  'two': () => { },

  // I would expect this be an error because the function returns a number

  'three': () => 0
};
```

However, type checking is enforced when invoking the functions:

```
// This is OK, as expected

funcMap['two'](0);

// This is an error, as expected

funcMap['two']();
```

---

Here is another example:

```
class Test {
  constructor(public func: (num: number) => void) { }
}

// I would expect an error

let x = new Test(() => { });

// This is OK, as expected

x.func(0);

// This is an error, as expected

x.func();
```

---

Is this behavior intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour is intentional.

Think of it this way: Does it matter whether a function accepts a number or no parameter? From the caller's perspective, it doesn't make a difference:

```
type INumFunc = (num: number) => any;

const a = (num: number) => { ... };
const b = () => { ... };

(<any>a)(num); // as intended
(<any>b)(num); // no negative side effect since `b` doesn't use the number
```

The same concept applies to return types. When a caller expects a function to return `void`, the return value stays unused. So, why care?

Comment: Reference for this being intentional? One of the points of Typescript (I think) is compile time checking, so from that perspective I would think there would be errors (and of course casting to `any` will void all warranties...).

Comment: The casting to `any` did confuse me a bit, but I think I get your point. For functions `two` and `three` there is an element of "it doesn't matter" at play. Function `two` doesn't use the parameter, so it doesn't matter if it's defined in the function signature. And for function `three`, the caller shouldn't be using the return value since it should expect `void`, so actually returning `number` shouldn't matter. That said, I still feel a bit uncomfortable about the checks being ignored.

Comment: In the underlying JavaScript, everything is going to be an `any`. The point of TypeScript compiler "errors" (even if it still can generate valid JavaScript) is to help the programmer *not* do stupid things like expect a number from a `void` function or pass a number to a function that does not expect one.

Comment: And in your example, `b(num)` (without the cast) *will* cause a TypeScript error. The caller does not care and should not need to know if `num` is used, but the language is designed to alert the user that something may be wrong. Also of note, the option you did not try - `(<any>a)();` will not error but also will not pass the expected number (used or not).

Comment: Yes it seems that function invocation always triggers errors, but assigning or passing functions with the wrong signature doesn't always trigger errors. I updated my question with another example.

Comment: Why is `INumFunc` not use anywhere in the example code following it's declaration?